# bulk download files from microsoft sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

bulk download from share point not downloading exact files and error.txt files are generated.

is there any application to bulk download sharepoint files

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnOyy.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5wf2.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Open with Explorer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-in-Explorer-or-View-with-File-Explorer-in-SharePoint-66B574BB-08B4-46B6-A6A0-435FD98194CC) function to open the document library in Windows Explorer, where you can select all the files you want and simply copy them to your destination. Note that this function only works in Internet Explorer, not in Edge or any other browser. There are ways to make it kind of work in modern browsers, but that requires custom code. You can, however, [save the location of the document library to the Quick access list](https://natechamberlain.com/2019/01/14/open-a-sharepoint-library-in-windows-explorer-and-save-it-to-quick-access/) to make it easier to find.

Another option seems to be the [SharePoint Bulk File Download](https://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-bulk-file-download-web-part/) web part, but I believe this is a paid tool that must be purchased after the trial.

I use Open with Explorer all the time, but I have never tried the mentioned web part.